# What do you call the opposite of a locked ward?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

As the heading says: what do you call the opposite of a locked ward? Or, put another way: what do you call inpatient care facilities that do not restrict patients/where patients can come and go freely (while still being inpatients)? I have tried googling ***unrestricted** care facility/treatment centre/treatment home* and ***open** care facility/treatment centre/treatment home* without any luck, but I can't think of any other possibilities.

If anyone could help me out here I'd be truly grateful!

Comment: I found "open wards" here https://www.nationalelfservice.net/mental-health/suicide/locked-wards-vs-open-wards-does-control-safety/

Comment: @Riolku Oh, lovely!! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'd only use "open wards" to contrast them with "locked wards". Most of them are just "wards" (assumed "open" by default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wards as you describe them are called **open wards**.
There are probably three categories based on the medical requirements of the patients and their potential to harm themselves or others.

- Open - unlocked
- Locked - but possibly communal spaces
- High security - locked and guarded/supervised

Answer (score 4):

I think the term you are looking for is an "open ward"; however, as someone that works in acute healthcare, I can tell you that the meanings of open, closed, restricted, unrestricted etc in connection with hospital wards will vary depending on context.

From a management perspective, an open ward is one that is currently in use and is admitting and discharging patients, while a closed ward is one that is not currently in use.

Open wards / locked wards can mean that the patient is either in a secure facility that they were prevented from leaving, or one that they entered and can leave voluntarily. However, most ward doors in hospitals remain locked except at prescribed visiting times, and wards where security is a particular concern (such as childrens wards or where there are vulnerable patients) may be permanently locked, even though the patients within are free to discharge themselves. So the definition of an "open ward" as being one that is not locked is not really that accurate.

Further, childrens wards often have "unrestricted" visiting hours for parents, meaning parents can stay with their admitted children 24 hours a day if they wish, so again the term "unrestricted" could mean different things in different contexts.

Comment: I deduce from the question that the OP is probably talking about mental health care rather than medical.

Comment: @PeterJennings Possibly, Sherlock, but that is an assumption. In any case, the definition of an "open ward" as being one that does not lock the door is hugely outdated. Also, in my experience of visiting "locked" mental health wards, some wards were locked by a code keypad with the code written on the wall right above it and the system relied on the patients not having the capacity to read the code. So again, it challenges the definition.

Comment: @PeterJennings You deduce correctly :) It didn't even occur to me that the situation would arise with strictly medical health care... Why would you have locked wards if the only issue is medical? Either way, I very much appreciate Astralbee's answer all the same :)

Comment: @Helen: An entire ward might be quarantined, for example if a COVID case arises in an area that is otherwise mostly or entirely free of the disease. This could also happen in the case of rare but highly transmissible diseases.

Comment: @Kevin Right – I didn't think of that, but you're right, of course :)